# Issue with drop down menu and tabs in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am using MDL tabs with angularjs. The Tab definition is:

```
<header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <a ng-href="#fixed-tab-1" ng-click="activateTab('Assets')"  class="mdl-layout__tab">Asset Protection</a>
        <a ng-href="#fixed-tab-2" ng-click="activateTab('Copies')"  class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Asset Copies</a>
        <a ng-href="#fixed-tab-3" ng-click="activateTab('Savings')" class="mdl-layout__tab">Asset Savings</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The table in tab 1 is:

```
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="x in restdata | filter:search | orderBy:btn:reverse">
                                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-typography--thin">{{ x.asset }}</td>
                                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
                                    <i id="ttadd01{{$index}}" class="material-icons icon-border md-15" 
                                       ng-click="tableAction(x.id)" ng-class="{ 'select600': x.actionselected}">
                                        add
                                    </i>
                                    <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="ttadd01{{$index}}">Add</div>
                                    <i  id="menu-action01{{$index}}" ng-click="tableList(x.id)" class="material-icons icon-border md-15">more_vert</i>
                                    <div ng-show=(x.selected)">
                                        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="menu-action01{{$index}}">
                                            <li ng-click="tableListAction($index)" class="mdl-menu__item" 
                                                ng-repeat="act01 in tableListActions"> 
                                                <i class="material-icons md-15">{{ act01.icon }}</i>{{ act01.name }}
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="menu-action01{{$index}}">More Options</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

On the second tab, very similar:

```
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="y in restdata | filter:search | orderBy:btn:reverse">
                                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-typography--thin">{{y.rental}}</td>
                                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
                                    <i id="ttadd02{{$index}}" class="material-icons icon-border md-15" 
                                       ng-click="tableAction(y.id)" ng-class="{ 'select600': y.actionselected}">
                                        add
                                    </i>
                                    <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="ttadd02{{$index}}">Add</div>
                                    <i  id="menu-action02{{$index}}" ng-click="tableList(y.id)" class="material-icons icon-border md-15">more_vert</i>
                                    <div ng-show="(y.selected)">
                                        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="menu-action02{{$index}}">
                                            <li ng-click="tableListAction($index)" class="mdl-menu__item" 
                                                ng-repeat="act02 in tableListActions"> 
                                                <i class="material-icons md-15">{{ act02.icon }}</i>{{ act02.name }}
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="menu-action02{{$index}}">More Options</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

FOr both tabs, data is pulled using REST calls (and is displayed correctly). What is not displayed correctly is the drop down menu menu-action01 and 02. On the first entry of any tab all is displayed well. On tab change, it stops displaying. I have verified that the .selected is set correctly in the javascript.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please verify your case on [this simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexEmashev/aokv0h8n/2/), without styles and REST calls?

```
    <div ng-show="(y.selected)">
      <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="menu-action02{{$index}}">
        <li ng-click="tableListAction($index)" class="mdl-menu__item" ng-repeat="act02 in tableListActions">
          <i class="material-icons md-15">{{ act02.icon }}</i>{{ act02.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript fragment:

```
    $scope.tableList = function(id){
  angular.forEach($scope.restdata, function(value, key) {
    value.selected = false;
  });
    $scope.restdata[id].selected = true;
};
```

Comment: Very nice example Alexander. I can see you sample code works as it should. I tried to post the same code in my project files and run into problems the way project is setup (routes etc). I will work through these. Your sample helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: In my env, the active tab prints only the static text and the tab navigation lead to page not found and are diverted to home page.